# UILabels in UIScrollView misaligned despite using CGRectIntegral?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, ios-simulator

I have a `UILabel` with an attributed string that I'm creating in a `UIScrollView`:

```
CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 10;
frame.size.width -= 10;
frame = CGRectIntegral(frame);

UILabel *textView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
textView.numberOfLines = 0;
textView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textView.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
[self addSubview:textView];
```

Despite ensuring the frame is set using `CGRectIntegral`, the iOS Simulator still shows the label as misaligned.

[image: Misaligned label]

To try to get rid of the misalignment, I also tried this without any luck:

```
textView.frame = CGRectIntegral(textView.frame);
textView.bounds = CGRectIntegral(textView.bounds);
```

Can a `UILabel` with attributed strings be properly aligned in scrollView?

Comment: Is the scroll view's contentOffset integral? What about contentInset?

Comment: @Answerbot What about the frame of the scrollview ?

Comment: are you calling sizeToFit at any point, or resetting the frame in any other way later on? Also, per what Dabrut said, is the scrollview's frame an integral rect? And is this taking place within a UITableViewCell or similar?

Comment: @JesseRusak The scrollViews inset and offset are all 0.0.

Comment: @dabrut The scrollView frame is also integral. {0,70,417,780}.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it will solve your problem, but you have nothing to lose to try another method :

```
CGRect frame = CGRectOffset(CGRectInset(self.view.frame,5,0),5,0);
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
label.text = @"Test";
[self addSubview:label];
```

If it's not working the error may come from your label itself (maybe `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`, `lineBreakMode`, `sizeToFit` or `contentMode`). All your label code is here ?

Try an incremental debugging because it may not come from the frame at all.

Comment: All great suggestions. It didn't fix my issue, but it seems likely that the problem lies somewhere in the superview hierachy which was too complex to attempt to include code for. In any case, appreciated all the suggestions.

Comment: Good luck with this ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have set the frame.origin.x =10; try by setting it to zero.

Comment: Why? Not sure why this would make any difference.

Comment: Becoz,the origin is nothing but the starting position of the label. x is the  starting position from left and y is the starting position from top.

Comment: The frame is already set to an integral with `CGRectIntegral`. Setting the x origin to an arbitrary number is not going to make a difference.

Comment: Setting the origin starting size must work. using CGRectIntegral will not set the origin of the label. if u want u can debug and check the origin points. before and after the use. Origin.x is the starting position. so setting origin.x must work for you.